# Zookeeper and ActiveMQ LevelDB replication non reliable

Tags: activemq-classic

In my current project we are trying to set up an activeMQ cluster with LevelDB replication. Our configuration has a ZooKeeper ensemble of three nodes and an ActiveMQ cluster of three nodes.

The following is the configuration used for activeMQ: (of course the hostname is different for each node in the cluster)

```
 <persistenceAdapter>
            <replicatedLevelDB 
                    replicas="3" 
                    bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:0" 
                    hostname="activemq1" 
                    zkAddress="zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181" 
                    zkPath="/activemq/leveldb-stores" 
            />
 </persistenceAdapter>
```

We start up three instances of zookeeper and three instances of activemq.  We observe that the zookeeper leader gets correctly elected. But in activeMQ cluster Master election is not happening. Go through the log we came to know that there is a authentication problem with zookeeper. (as per the log, I am having less knowledge in zookeeper/activemq). Herewith I pasted the logs for reference.

```
INFO: Loading '/opt/activemq//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
INFO: Starting in foreground, this is just for debugging purposes (stop process by pressing CTRL+C)
INFO: Creating pidfile /data/activemq/activemq.pid
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_91 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Heap sizes: current=62976k  free=59998k  max=932352k
JVM args: -Xms64M -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/activemq/conf.tmp/login.config -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/activemq//tmp - 
Dactivemq.classpath=/opt/activemq/conf.tmp:/opt/activemq//../lib/: -Dactivemq.home=/opt/activemq/ -
Dactivemq.base=/opt/activemq/ -Dactivemq.conf=/opt/activemq/conf.tmp -Dactivemq.data=/data/activemq
Extensions classpath:[/opt/activemq/lib,/opt/activemq/lib/camel,/opt/activemq/lib/optional,/opt/activemq/lib/web,/opt/activemq/lib/extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /opt/activemq
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /opt/activemq
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /opt/activemq/conf.tmp
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /data/activemq
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@7823a2f9: startup date [Sat Jun 17 09:15:51 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
INFO | JobScheduler using directory: /data/activemq/localhost/scheduler
INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: Replicated LevelDB[/data/activemq/leveldb, ip-172-20-44-97.ec2.internal:2181,ip-172-20-45-105.ec2.internal:2181,ip-172-20-48-226.ec2.internal:2181//activemq/leveldb-stores]
INFO | Starting StateChangeDispatcher
INFO | Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
INFO | Client environment:host.name=activemq-m1n59
INFO | Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_91
INFO | Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
INFO | Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
INFO | Client environment:java.class.path=/opt/activemq//bin/activemq.jar
INFO | Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
INFO | Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/opt/activemq//tmp
INFO | Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
INFO | Client environment:os.name=Linux
INFO | Client environment:os.arch=amd64
INFO | Client environment:os.version=4.4.65-k8s
INFO | Client environment:user.name=root
INFO | Client environment:user.home=/root
INFO | Client environment:user.dir=/tmp
INFO | Initiating client connection, connectString=ip-172-20-44-97.ec2.internal:2181,ip-172-20-45-105.ec2.internal:2181,ip-172-20-48-226.ec2.internal:2181 sessionTimeout=2000        watcher=org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.groups.ZKClient@4b41dd5c
WARN | SASL configuration failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file: '/opt/activemq/conf.tmp/login.config'. Will continue connection to Zookeeper server without SASL authentication, if Zookeeper server allows it.
WARN | unprocessed event state: AuthFailed
INFO | Opening socket connection to server ip-172-20-45-105.ec2.internal/172.20.45.105:2181
WARN | Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)[:1.8.0_91] at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)[:1.8.0_91] at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965] at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
WARN | SASL configuration failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file: '/opt/activemq/conf.tmp/login.config'. Will continue connection to Zookeeper server without SASL authentication, if Zookeeper server allows it.
INFO | Opening socket connection to server ip-172-20-48-226.ec2.internal/172.20.48.226:2181
WARN | unprocessed event state: AuthFailed
WARN | Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)[:1.8.0_91] at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)[:1.8.0_91] at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361) [zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965] at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
WARN | SASL configuration failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file: '/opt/activemq/conf.tmp/login.config'. Will continue connection to Zookeeper server without SASL authentication, if Zookeeper server allows it.
INFO | Opening socket connection to server ip-172-20-44-97.ec2.internal/172.20.44.97:2181
WARN | unprocessed event state: AuthFailed
WARN | Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)[:1.8.0_91] at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)[:1.8.0_91] at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965] at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
```

Please help to get out from this problem.

If anyone having idea of deploying Zookeeper with ActiveMQ cluster in Kubernetes please share your ideas. since we are trying to deploy it in Kubernetes.